# Contador de diferentes registros con condicionales en una columna SQL

Tags: php, postgresql

actualmente estoy realizando un contador de registros múltiples dentro de la base de datos para mostrarlos en la vista con php. Realice el primero contador simple de una misma columna con este código, teniendo en cuenta que `futbol` es un dato principal en conjunto con otros deportes como `Baloncesto`, `Beisbol` y `edad` es el dato secundario.

```
if($value->equipo == 'futbol'){
            $efutbol++;
        }
```

Ahora debo contar en dos columnas relacionando los datos, un ejemplo de ello seria

```
`if($value->equipo == 'futbol' and $value->edad == '14'){
            $edadf14++;
        }`
`if($value->equipo == 'futbol' and $value->edad == '15'){
            $edadf15++;
        }`
```

Haciendo el if de las 2 columnas contando todos los registros ocupa mas de 1600 lineas de código. ¿Como se optimizaría para lograr la menor cantidad de lineas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si entendí bien tu requerimiento, pero según lo que entendí, lo que buscas se resuelve mucho mas facil con una query sql.

No conozco la estructura de tus tablas, pero este ejemplo (muy sencillo) te va a servir como ayuda para armar las queries que necesitas.

Datos: definí 3 tablas, deportes, personas y personas_deportes (los deportes que practica cada persona).

```
CREATE TABLE deportes (
id int,
nombre varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO deportes VALUES
(1, 'futbol'),
(2, 'Baloncesto'),
(3, 'Baseball');

CREATE TABLE personas(
id int,
nombre  varchar(100),
edad int);

INSERT INTO personas VALUES
(1, 'Juan', 20),
(2, 'Carlos', 22),
(3, 'Perdo', 25);

CREATE TABLE personas_deportes (
id_persona int,
id_deporte int
);

INSERT INTO personas_deportes VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 2);
```

**Primera query:** cantidad de personas que practican cada deporte.

```
SELECT d.nombre AS deporte, count(*) FILTER (WHERE pd.id_deporte IS NOT NULL) AS cantidad_personas
FROM deportes d
LEFT JOIN personas_deportes pd ON d.id = pd.id_deporte
GROUP BY d.nombre
ORDER BY d.nombre;
```

Salida:

| deporte | cantidad_personas |
| --- | --- |
| Baloncesto | 2 |
| Baseball | 0 |
| futbol | 2 |

**Segunda query:** Cantidad de personas que practican cada deporte por edad.

```
WITH edades AS (SELECT generate_series(MIN(edad), MAX(edad), 1) AS edad
                FROM personas),
                
     dep_edades AS (SELECT *
                    FROM deportes d
                    CROSS JOIN edades)
                    
SELECT de.nombre AS deporte, de.edad, count(*) FILTER (WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL) AS cantidad_personas
FROM dep_edades de
LEFT JOIN personas_deportes pd ON de.id = pd.id_deporte
LEFT JOIN personas p ON p.id = pd.id_persona AND p.edad = de.edad
GROUP BY de.nombre, de.edad
ORDER BY de.nombre, de.edad;
```

Salida:

| deporte | edad | cantidad_personas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Baloncesto | 20 | 0 |
| Baloncesto | 21 | 0 |
| Baloncesto | 22 | 1 |
| Baloncesto | 23 | 0 |
| Baloncesto | 24 | 0 |
| Baloncesto | 25 | 1 |
| Baseball | 20 | 0 |
| Baseball | 21 | 0 |
| Baseball | 22 | 0 |
| Baseball | 23 | 0 |
| Baseball | 24 | 0 |
| Baseball | 25 | 0 |
| futbol | 20 | 1 |
| futbol | 21 | 0 |
| futbol | 22 | 1 |
| futbol | 23 | 0 |
| futbol | 24 | 0 |
| futbol | 25 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=75ff096d290b4113098ed26cca1dab00)

---

**Optimización php**

Hay formas de optimizar tu código `php`, por ejemplo utilizando arreglos, con los deportes y las edades (pero es mucho mas simple resolverlo con una query sql, ya que no necesitarías iterar sobre los datos):

```
<?php

//Por ejemplo inicializas un arreglo con los deportes y edades en cero, y vas incrementando en uno de la siguiente manera 
//El siguiente código estaría dentro de un bucle (donde lees los datos que obtienes de la base de datos):

$resultado[$deporte][$edad]++;

?>
```

De esta manera ya no necesitarías todos esos `if`.